# Mockito / Junit5 org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError for getter()

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

If I make a JUnit Mockito test in the following method, it fails with *org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not null*. But the Mockito-(Parameter-)Test before with verify() and Assertions.assertNotNull() is ok. What am I doing wrong or what I don't understand? Here's my code:

JUnit5/mock-Test:

```
@Mock
private MyentityAServiceImpl myentityAServiceImplmock;
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<MyentityA> myentityAArgument;
@Mock
private MyentityBdao myentityBdaomock;
@Mock
private MyentityB myentityBmock;
@Mock
private Logger loggermock;
@InjectMocks
private MyentityBServiceImpl teServiceImpl;

@Test
public void setMyentityAOfTeIfNullByLanr17() {
    myentityBmock.setLanr7( "1234567" );
    final MyentityA myentityA = new MyentityA();
    mockito.when( myentityAServiceImplmock.findMyentityAByLanr17( myentityBmock.getLanr7() ) ).thenReturn( myentityA );
    mockito.when( myentityBdaomock.save( myentityBmock ) ).thenReturn( myentityBmock );
    myentityBmock = teServiceImpl.setMyentityAOfTeIfNullByLanr17( myentityBmock );
    mockito.verify( myentityBmock ).setMyentityA( myentityAArgument.capture() );
    Assertions.assertNotNull( myentityAArgument );
    Assertions.assertNotNull( myentityBmock.getMyentityA() );  // --> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>
}
```

Method to test:

```
  public MyentityB setMyentityAOfTeIfNullByLanr17( final MyentityB entity ) {
    MyentityA myentityA = entity.getMyentityA();
    if ( myentityA != null ) {
        return entity;
    }
    final String lanr17 = entity.getLanr7();
    myentityA = myentityAServiceImpl.findMyentityAByLanr17( lanr17 );
    if ( myentityA != null ) {
        entity.setMyentityA( myentityA );
        entity.setModuser( "root" );
        return myentityBdao.save( entity );
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry your testing code is really too complex.
It describes too finely the flow of invocations of the objects manipulated in the method under test.
Besides you mock many things : dependencies, parameters of the method under tests.
At last you assign to the variable referencing the mocked parameter the return of the method under test.  It makes things really unclear.

A test has to be straight understandable and that is not.
It took me about 5 mn to understand the error cause. It is a lot for such a simple code.

This assertion failure :

```
Assertions.assertNotNull( myentityBmock.getMyentityA() );  // --> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>
```

is due to the fact that in the tested method `getMynEntityA()`  can only be `null` as `myentityBmock` is a mock and setting a field as you do here will have no effect on the real field and the associated getter behavior :

```
if ( myentityA != null ) {
    entity.setMyentityA( myentityA ); // here you invoke a mocked method.
    entity.setModuser( "root" );
    return myentityBdao.save( entity );
}
```

In fact with your way of testing that mainly describes the invocation flow of the tested method, that is enough :

```
mockito.verify( myentityBmock ).setMyentityA( myentityAArgument.capture() );
```

as you cannot test the side effect of `setMyentityA()`.

But really I strongly advise you to unit test your method without mocking the parameter of the tested method.
It could look like  :

```
@Test
public void setMyentityAOfTeIfNullByLanr17() {
    MyentityB entityB = new MyentityB(...) ;
    entityB.setLanr7( "1234567" );
    final MyentityA myentityA = new MyentityA();
    mockito.when( myentityAServiceImplmock.findMyentityAByLanr17( entityB.getLanr7() ) ).thenReturn( myentityA );
    mockito.when( myentityBdaomock.save(entityB) ).thenReturn(entityB);

    // action
    MyentityB entityActualB = teServiceImpl.setMyentityAOfTeIfNullByLanr17(entityB);

    // Perform content/logic assertion and no flow assertion :
    Assertions.assertEquals(myEntityA, entityActualB.getMyEntityA());
    Assertions.assertEquals("root", entityActualB.getModuser());
}
```

No tested code at all but it should help you to understand my intention.

Comment: It works now. As you said, too many things were mixed and mocked which make it too complicated. I understand my error now - thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that you grasped the overall idea.

Comment: I see what you mean ;-)